# CakePHP validation error on an optional field

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm creating a form in CakePHP, where there is a field that is output only on certain conditions. However, when it is not output, validation invalidates it. I'm not sure where I did wrong?

Validation in Model:

```
public $validate = array(
    'extra_requirement_ok' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule'     => array('comparison', '!=', 0),
            //'required' => false,
            'message'  => 'Must'
        ),
    ),  
);
```

The input in the view:

```
if ($check) { 
    echo $this->Form->input('extra_requirement_ok'); 
}
```

EDITED:

When I check the data that is passed when is submitted, array key for `extra_requirement_ok` does not exist. But I created a custom validation and check the array that is passed to the custom validation function, it returns `extra_requirement_ok = '0'`. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.

I set 0 as defined value in the database, as the data is being saved, 0 is generated by default and that triggered validation. Now the database column is set to NULL and it's fine now.